# Fatal error when extending included class

Tags: php, oop

I am trying a very simple thing here but it doesn't seem to work. Take a look at this code:

```
include 'custom/mainclass.php';

$child = new childClass();

class childClass extends mainClass {
}
```

Apparently childClass() cannot be found (According to php).. I'm 100% sure I'm doing something very stupid in the way of ordering my code.

I already searched the web but from what I understand I'm doing nothing wrong..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to declare your classes in your code first **before** using them.

```
include 'custom/mainclass.php';

class childClass extends mainClass {

}

$child = new childClass(); //Create an instance after the class has been declared
```

**EDIT:**

After some research it turned out, that you can actually use a class before declaring it.
**But**, declaration of the class and all parent classes *must be in the same file*.

So if you declare a parent class in one file and a child class in another, it won't work.

Also, you must declare parent classes first. After that you can extend them.

Comment: Yep that seemed to work. But i'm curious why my script worked before where I didn't extend anything and had my class deceleration below the usage

Comment: I am not sure you could use it before declaration. Actually your file `custom/mainclass.php` contains declaration of a main class, and you included it first -> then used.

Comment: What I mean, before I didn't extend nor did I include anything. I just had a tiny script, with the class declared at the bottom. I used the class at the top of my script without any errors. When I extended it, all of a sudden the order started to matter

Comment: Try extending the parent class, but declare it in the same file (i.e. do not use `include`) - this should work. Reason: declarations are handled before the code is executed (i.e. PHP processes the declaration code, then the rest). However, `include` is a run-time operation and runs _inline_ with the code (after declarations), so when the extending class is declared, the parent class doesn't exist yet, which will cause the extending class to not exist, too. | Complex stuff - I don't fully understand it myself - but this seems to be roughly how it works.

Comment: @Ortix92 Yeah, you were right. I edited my answer. `Lukas` also pointed it out right.

Answer (score 1):

Same as with Variables, Functions or other language constructs,

First declare, then use.