# Class not found (in PHP)

Tags: php, fatal-error, classnotfound

This code works without problems:

```
<?php
namespace NamespaceA;
class A extends \NamespaceB\B {}

namespace NamespaceB;
class B {}
```

But why the following code cause **Fatal error: Class 'NamespaceB\B' not found in ...file**?

```
<?php
namespace NamespaceA;
class A extends \NamespaceB\B {}

namespace NamespaceB;
class B extends \NamespaceC\C {}

namespace NamespaceC;
class C {}
```

And this code also works without problems:

```
<?php
namespace NamespaceA;
class A extends \NamespaceB\B {}

namespace NamespaceC;
class C {}

namespace NamespaceB;
class B extends \NamespaceC\C {}
```

**UPD:**
Without any namespace, also  **Fatal error: Class 'B' not found in ...file**:

```
<?php

class A extends B {}

class B extends C {}

class C {}
```

Works without problems:

```
<?php

class A extends B {}

class B {}
```

Comment: Heck of a rabbit hole: This works `php -r 'class B extends C {} class D extends C{} class E extends D{} class C{}'` but this doesn't `php -r 'class B extends C {} class D extends C{} class C extends A{} class E extends D{} class A{}'`

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Classes must be defined before they are used. If you want the class A to extend the class B, you will have to define the class B first. The order in which the classes are defined is important.

**Edit:**

Found more:

[Fatal error when extending included class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16462937/fatal-error-when-extending-included-class)

After some research, it became clear, that actually you can use a class before declaring it. But, declaration of the class and all parent classes must be in the same file.

So if you declare a parent class in one file and a child class in another, it won't work.

Also, you must declare parent classes first. After that you can extend them.

**Edit Number 2**:

Okay so I did some more research on the issue. There is probably some internal implementation detail that currently allows for the one case to work (my guess would be something regarding auto-loading) however this is something that could change at any time and should never be relied upon.

Comment: How do you then explain that the code works without problems?
```
    <?php
    namespace NamespaceA;
    class A extends \NamespaceB\B {}
    
    namespace NamespaceB;
    class B {}
```

Comment: Run the second example code (not using different files)

Comment: "when the extending class is declared, the parent class doesn't exist yet, which will cause the extending class to not exist, too." From my findings the interpreter reads the declaration first. So for your third example it declares C, then B which extends C, then A which extends B. In example 2 C is declared, then A which declares B which hasn't been declared yet so it throws an error.

Comment: This answer does not explain the behavior exposed by the question.

Comment: Totally agree with the part *"that could change at any time and should never be relied upon."*

Answer (score 0):

First use include_once() to add all the files in your index file and when your are extends to any class, instantiate that parent class first.Example:

```
index.php-->
<?php
    include_once('parentClass.php');
    include_once('childClass.php');

    $parentObj = new parent();
    $childObj = new child();
?>

child.php-->
<?php
  class child extends parent{
   function __construct(){

    }
  }
?>
```